# Why variable comparison is running slow?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

One of my procedure calling the calling the function and bind the return value to variable. Please have a look below:

This query is executing within procedure.

old query

```sql
--lc_tmp_year  is variable declare at procedure level
--this call taking 3 secs to execute
lc_tmp_year = EmpPackage.GetEmployeeCodeYear(emp_id);

select * from employeePlans
where code_year = lc_tmp_year;
```

new query

```sql
--this running faster than the above one - within secs
select * from employeePlans
where code_year = EmpPackage.GetEmployeeCodeYear(emp_id);;
```

I am surprised why new query is running faster than old query.

Did anyone have the clue?

Comment: Please provide information on tables size and the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be that query optimizer in the new query, can see relation with *employee*
and is able to make optimization with internal inner joining, behind scene, and further, is able to use possible indexes. In the old query, pure value *lc_tmp_year* is present to select statement and in some bad case it basically executes sequential comparing across whole *employeePlans* relation, or at least with not used indexing options as used in new query, what, at the end implies better result for new query.
Of course, it all depends of DDL statements for creating database and particular relations, but, if you have such results, this could be explanation.